# Different Portrait layouts in android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-screen-support

Initially I developed my application for phones only in portrait mode. But now, I want to shift that to tablets as well, but in portrait mode only. My question is, can we define different layouts for portrait mode for different screen sizes. It works on tablets but the UI is stretched. If yes, how..? If someone could give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can define the same layout for different sized devices.

Assuming you have the layout folder already, you can create another one called 'layout-xlarge'.

In here, create an xml layout with the **same name** as the one in the layout folder. Now when you run the app, only 10" tablets (devices designated as having extra large screens) will use the 'layout-xlarge' folder.

All other smaller devices will use the 'layout' folder.

Your folder structure will look like so:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

You can do the same for small and large screens, among others.

This is a rather brief description and you would do well to read this when you get a chance:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to create 3 layout in your resource folder and each one has same name xml file

that are

1. layout  (contaning a.xml, b.xml, c.xml)
2. layout-large (also contaning a.xml, b.xml, c.xml)
3. layout-small (also contaning a.xml, b.xml, c.xml)

check your application on different size of emulators like QVGA, HVGA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can develop define different layouts for portrait mode for different screen sizes

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large screen size for land scale
```

by default res/layout/my_layout.xml this means you are going to create my_layout for portrait mode.

just take care of folder hierarchy .

[for more details](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)